# How do i create this php array from this csv?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I need to create an array from a csv file that looks like this.

```
$responseMessages = array(
    '111111'    => array('body' => 'test me, We will give you up to 3001 for your 2010 toyota camry. Visit http://testme.whatever.com or call +17777777777'),
    '222222'    => array('body' => 'test you, We will give you up to 3002 for your 2011 nissan maxima. Visit http://testyou.whatever.com or call +17777777777'),
    '333333'    => array('body' => 'test him, We will give you up to 3003 for your 2012 honda civic. Visit http://testhim.whatever.com or call +17777777777'),
    '444444'    => array('body' => 'test her, We will give you up to 3004 for your 2013 hyundai sonata. Visit http://testher.whatever.com or call +17777777777'),
    '555555'    => array('body' => 'test them, We will give you up to 3005 for your 2014 subaru legacy. Visit http://testthem.whatever.com or call +17777777777'),
    '666666'    => array('body' => 'test us, We will give you up to 3006 for your 2015 acura integra. Visit http://testus.whatever.com or call +17777777777')
);
```

The csv looks like this:

```
first   last    year    make    model   value   code    url
test    me      2010    toyota  camry   3001    111111  http://testme.whatever.com
test    you     2011    nissan  maxima  3002    222222  http://testyou.whatever.com
test    him     2012    honda   civic   3003    333333  http://testhim.whatever.com
test    her     2013    hyundai sonata  3004    444444  http://testher.whatever.com
test    them    2014    subaru  legacy  3005    555555  http://testthem.whatever.com
test    us      2015    acura   integra 3006    666666  http://testus.whatever.com
```

This is the php i'm using:

```
$phone = "+17777777777";
$handle = fopen("test.csv", "r");
$row = 0;
$responseMessages = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE && $row < 8) {
    if ($data[6] !== "code") { //leave out header line
        $code = $data[6];
        $upc = $data[0]." ".$data[1].", We will give you up to ".$data[5]." for your ".$data[2]." ".$data[3]." ".$data[4].". Visit ".$data[7]." or call ".$phone;
        $responseMessages['\''.$code.'\'']['\'body\''] = '\''.$upc.'\'';
        $row++;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $responseMessages );
echo "</pre>";
```

This is the array that is being produced:

```
Array
(
    ['111111'] => Array
        (
            ['body'] => 'test me, We will give you up to 3001 for your 2010 toyota camry. Visit http://testme.whatever.com or call +17777777777'
        )

    ['222222'] => Array
        (
            ['body'] => 'test you, We will give you up to 3002 for your 2011 nissan maxima. Visit http://testyou.whatever.com or call +17777777777'
        )

    ['333333'] => Array
        (
            ['body'] => 'test him, We will give you up to 3003 for your 2012 honda civic. Visit http://testhim.whatever.com or call +17777777777'
        )

    ['444444'] => Array
        (
            ['body'] => 'test her, We will give you up to 3004 for your 2013 hyundai sonata. Visit http://testher.whatever.com or call +17777777777'
        )

    ['555555'] => Array
        (
            ['body'] => 'test them, We will give you up to 3005 for your 2014 subaru legacy. Visit http://testthem.whatever.com or call +17777777777'
        )

    ['666666'] => Array
        (
            ['body'] => 'test us, We will give you up to 3006 for your 2015 acura integra. Visit http://testus.whatever.com or call +17777777777'
        )

)
```

Kind of looks right, but not really. Not sure if i need the commas that are between each array, or if the word array needs to be lowercase, but the main thing is all the ['body'] tags can't have brackets, and no brackets around the codes either. Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong, and if there is a different array creation method I need to be using, and what that is? Thank you.

Comment: Those 2 outputs look identical to me. What's different?

Comment: https://eval.in/995596 your output is the same as the $responseMessages array you gave. Just the formatting is a bit different - the result of how `print_r()` formats things, as opposed to how you write them as code.

Comment: well, when i hit the application with the code, it doesn't do response properly using csv method, as when i create the array myself, but if csv has 10,000 lines, not going to do a 10,000 line php array. that's why i needed an auto array maker in the correct format that the app needs.

Comment: using twilio service and this exact example, minus the media (image). https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134267-Building-an-SMS-keyword-response-application ... basically need to use that same code but reading from a csv file instead of a hard-coded php array of all the different code and body combinations.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your meaning. In the question you said "This is the array that is being produced:" . That array (which I assume is the output of your code above) is exactly the same as the example array you defined in the question as $responseMessages. You said you wanted to create an array the same as $responseMessages, and your code already does that. Therefore we had to assume it's working correctly. If you're saying it's _not_ working correctly, you're going to have to explain in more detail, because based on the information in your question, it appears that everything is ok.

Comment: if you go to that link from twilio, there is an if/else statement that says if one of the keywords is given, then reply with one of the response messages that match the keyword, otherwise reply with a default message.  so when i try to use the code, the default message comes back whether or not i put in one of the keywords. i don't know where the problem is. this is why i ask for help.

Comment: hardcoding the array works, but trying to build the array from a csv file is not working for some reason.  maybe it's this line here, not sure: $responseMessages['\''.$code.'\'']['\'body\''] = '\''.$upc.'\'';  it's like i'm faking the output with all those backslashes to force the quotes.

Comment: none of that is anything to do with what you asked in the question, which is probably why I was confused. In particular "trying to build the array from a csv file is not working" directly contradicts your assertion in the question that "This is the array that is being produced:" which implies the code is working correctly. Do you see why it was unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like changing this:

```
$responseMessages['\''.$code.'\'']['\'body\''] = '\''.$upc.'\'';
```

to this:

```
$responseMessages[$code]['body'] = $upc;
```

made it work.